# Animating an image from grayscale to color from left to right

Tags: jquery, html, css

**Disclaimer**: I don't want to move the image from left to right. I've gone through quite a bit of answers here in Stack Overflow and all of them were referring to moving the image from left to right.

I've tried transitions and playing with background-positions. I want my animation that turns a grayscale image to a coloured image from left to right. Like the colour should appear from left to right. The animation should be like a coloured version of the image overlapping the grayscaled image from left to right.

Here is what I've made so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
      $("#pp").addClass('prog_load')
    });
});

</script>

<style>

.button {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ff0000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px #000000;
}

.button:active {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #000000;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 4px #000000;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.prog_bar {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}


.prog_load {
filter: grayscale(0%);

transition: all 10s ease;


}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<button class = "button" id = "button"> Claik meh </button>
    <img src = imgurl class = "prog_bar" id = "pp">

</body>
</html>
```

[codeshare.io](https://codeshare.io/aVNOgb)

All what it does is just convert the grayscale image to color.

Comment: You're trying to mix up two different kinds of transforms. A solution would be to animate another picture over the old one, with the greyscale already applied.

Comment: @Roberrrt I see, thank you very much for clearing it out. I considered that way of going about to do it but it sounded like a hassle so I constantly pushed the thought away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what Roberrt was talking about...

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/xbq1v7fg/4/)

```js
$(".effect img").each(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  imgS = $this.attr("src");

  $this.after("<div class='effect-dup'><img src='" + imgS + "' /></div>")
});

$("button").click(function() {
  $this = $(this);

  $(this).prev().addClass("cool-effect");
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.effect {
  position: relative;
}

.effect-dup {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: width 1s ease-in-out;
}

.effect-dup.cool-effect {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
  <button>
    See cool effect
  </button>
</div>

<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" />
  <button>
    See cool effect
  </button>
</div>
```

**Pure CSS & HTML**:

```css
body {
  margin: 0; /*neccessary for effect*/
}

.effect {
  position: relative;
}

.effect-dup {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  animation: width 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes width {
  from {
    width: 0;
  }
  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" />
  <div class='effect-dup'><img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature" /></div>
</div>

<div class="effect">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" />
  <div class='effect-dup'>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fiddle! Much much appreciated!

Comment: Precisely, well made!